# Python-Flask Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'unicode'>, <type 'list'>

Tags: python, firebase, flask

Hi I am trying to download an excel file from the below mentioned code, I am querying the data's from the firebase database. 
But when i try to run this it is giving me a unicode Exception. 
can anyone help me solve this?
Thanks in advance.

```
@mod_drprax_backend.route('/download-excel/', methods=['GET'])
def export_db():

    array = []
    args = get_query_args(request)
    ref = db.collection(u'Providers')
    providersList, total = firebase_admin_query_helper(ref, args)
    pro = providersList[0]

    collect = zip(pro.keys(), pro.values())

    for data in collect:
        providerDetails = [data]
        array.append(providerDetails)

    return excel.make_response_from_array([array],"xls",file_name=u"excel_doc" )
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Looks like you use an operation on two dtypes that do not match in a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provide, you do not respect the type contracts. Since `zip(..)` returns a list of tuples (here 2-tuples), this means that the `data` in the `for` loop is in fact a 2-tuple (apparently `(unicode, list)`). You can not feed this to the excel export.

You will thus need to do some *linearization*. For example:

```
@mod_drprax_backend.route('/download-excel/', methods=['GET'])
def export_db():
    array = []
    args = get_query_args(request)
    ref = db.collection(u'Providers')
    providersList, total = firebase_admin_query_helper(ref, args)
    pro = providersList[0]

    for ky, vls in pro.items():
        for vl in vls:
            for subky, subvl in vl.items():
                providerDetails = [ky, subky, subvl]
        array.append(providerDetails)

        return excel.make_response_from_array([array],"xls",file_name=u"excel_doc" )
```

Note that if `pro` is a dictionary, you can use `.items()` instead, we can furthermore use list comprehension:

```
@mod_drprax_backend.route('/download-excel/', methods=['GET'])
def export_db():
    args = get_query_args(request)
    ref = db.collection(u'Providers')
    providersList, total = firebase_admin_query_helper(ref, args)
    pro = providersList[0]

    array = [
        [ky, subky, subvl]
        for ky, vls in pro.items()
        for vl in vls
        for subky, subvl in vl.items()
    ]

    return excel.make_response_from_array([array],"xls",file_name=u"excel_doc" )
```

Comment: Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'dict'> now i'm getting this exception.

Comment: @DineshJosephite: can you post the content of your `pro` variable (together but how you want to render it).

Comment: {u'ActiveChats': [{u'Id': u'abRMVBl30bTO7huMKvdgiUEjC8m2', u'Name': u'Sushma Benakatti'}, {u'Name': u'Sushma B', u'Id': u'pFrCGMI1VRZVCDCvPa837YjRin62'}]} I want this data to be available on the excel sheet. @Willem

Comment: @DineshJosephite: edited. This will probably work, although as said before, you need to alter it based on the *way* you want to exprt the data.